# firestore query inside array values

Tags: google-cloud-firestore

Does firestore know how to query inside this structure for red shirts ?

```
Products:{
    "prod_1_key": ["red","xl","shoes"],
    "prod_2_key": ["blue","xs","hats"],
    "prod_3_key": ["blue","xs","shirt"],
    "prod_4_key": ["yellow","xxl","pants"],
    "prod_5_key": ["green","xl","shirts"],
    "prod_6_key": ["red","xxl","shirt"],    
}
```

Comment: Please edit your question and add your database structure as a screenshot.

Answer (score 0):

The only operation that Firestore has to [query an array field(https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries#array_membership) is `arrayContains`, which checks whether the exact item you pass to the query exists in a specifically named field. You can use at most one `arrayContains` operation in a query.

So you can check whether `prod_6_key` contains `red`, or `prod_5_key` contains shirt, but you can't check whether any of the 6 product fields contains both `red` and `shirt`.

To allow this query, consider adding a new field that combines the two values of each product that you want to search on. Say:

```
product_colors: [
  { color: "red", product: "shoes" },
  { color: "blue", product: "hats" },
  { color: "blue", product: "shirt" },
  ...
]
```

Now you can query this field with a single `arrayContains` for a red shirt.

Adding additional fields to allow a specific use-case is quite common in NoSQL databases. If you are new to this, I recommend checking out [NoSQL data modeling](https://highlyscalable.wordpress.com/2012/03/01/nosql-data-modeling-techniques/) and [Getting to know Cloud Firestore](https://firestore.video).

Comment: Thanks Frank, the whole purpose of the idea is to reduce the size of the stored data by eliminating the keys and storing data inside an array that has a specific structure like [category,color,product_name,size, ... etc ].

Comment: The structure you came up with doesn't allow the query you want to perform on it (see the first two paragraphs of my answer). So if you want to perform that query, you'll need a different structure like the one I have in the second part of my answer. ¯\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: To expand on Frank's comment:  the cost of *size* for documents is almost negligible - this is NOT the right point for optimization.  More importantly: for NoSQL decide *what questions/queries* you want to ask your database *first*, and *then* design your database schema to make those queries easier.